# Confidence interval for difference of means

Tags: python, confidence-interval, t-test, biostatistics

Doing exercise on Bioequivalence Study, taking data from [here](http://jse.amstat.org/v12n1/datasets.bradstreet.html#senn1993).
Model defined as $\log Y_{i,j,k} = \mu + s_{i,k} + \pi_j + \tau_{[i=j]} + \lambda_{[j=2]\cdot(1+[i=1])} + \varepsilon_{i,j,k}$, where $\mu$ is common mean, $s_{i,k}$ is influence of test's subject k from $i$ group, $\tau_1$ - influence of drug X; $\tau_0$ - inf. of placebo. $\lambda_2$ - influence of drug X in first period on second period results and $\lambda_1$ - same for placebo. $\lambda_0 = 0$; $\varepsilon_{i,j,k}$ is an error during measurement.
Data is represented the next way:
[image]

We assume $s_{i,k} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_s^2)$ and independent, $\varepsilon_{i,j,k} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_s^2)$ and independent. Other parameters fixed by: $\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 0$, $\tau_0 + \tau_1 = 0$,$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 0$. We will use means: $\mu_{i, j}$ where $i$ is a group number and $j$ - a period number.

**Note** that $\mu_{1, 1} - \mu_{1, 2} = (\pi_1 - \pi_2) + (\tau_1 - \tau_0) - \lambda_2$ and $\mu_{2, 1} - \mu_{2, 2} = (\pi_1 - \pi_2) + (\tau_0 - \tau_1) - \lambda_1$. So, from equality of this two differencies implies $\tau_1 - \tau_0 = 0$. Using this note, we will take samples as differences of periods from two groups.

**I need to** test the next hypothesis: $H_0:\tau_1 - \tau_0 < \log 0.8 \lor \tau_1 - \tau_0 > \log 1.25$.

I think I can solve it by finding **confidence interval** for difference $\tau_1 - \tau_0 = 0$. Also I was told to use Welch t-test (which is about testing for means equality), since our standard deviations not equal (and means are not by the way).
I'm trying to find it, but got failed however. Also was told that statistic from Welch t-test is approximately from student's distribution **only** under assumption $H_0$ is correct. But it remains unknown (for me) what distribution it is when $H_0$ is **not** correct.

In general, **my question is**: how to find confidence interval on $\tau_1 - \tau_0$, using Welch t-test? But **particularly**, question is: what distribution statistic from Welch t-test when $H_0$ is **not** correct?

My approach in Python (which is simple welch t-test):

```py
def welch_t_test(sample1, sample2, alpha):
    n = len(sample1); m = len(sample2)
    std1 = np.std(sample1, ddof=1); std2 = np.std(sample2, ddof=1)
    ddof = (std1**2/n + std2**2/m)**2/((std1**2/n)**2/(n-1) + (std2**2/m)**2/(m-1))
    diff = np.mean(sample1) - np.mean(sample2)
    return diff - ss.t.ppf(q=1-alpha,df=ddof)*np.sqrt(std1**2/n + std2**2/m), 
           diff + ss.t.ppf(q=1-alpha,df=ddof)*np.sqrt(std1**2/n + std2**2/m)
```

Comment: That's how hypothesis testing works: You assume that H0 is true. And another thing: Is the null hypothesis $\tau_1 - \tau_0 \in [\log(0.8), \log(1.25)]$ or is this the alternative hypothesis?

Comment: @dipetkov 1. I understand that, but still need this result knowing I have not equal means. I.e. it's not "hypothesis testing" in a strictly sense. 2. It is null hypothesis

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to do estimation rather than hypothesis testing. Your question is not clear and there is a lot of irrelevant detail. You can read previous CV posts about confidence intervals for difference in means, eg. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486722/why-use-welchs-t-interval-or-pooled-t-interval-for-mean-differences) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396867/how-to-estimate-the-confidence-interval-of-the-difference-of-means).

Comment: Until you do the statistical test, you do not _know_ that the means are unequal. (Actually you don't even _know_ that after the test. If the null hypothesis isn't supported, you just have _evidence_ that the means aren't equal.) The observed mean values might be numerically distinct, but you don't know whether that difference might represent a true difference in mean values until you take the error estimates into account with a statistical test.